# How do I Refresh Vuex getter when using it with local storage?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've a getter (with no state, just using it for convenience) which shows user his notifications:

```
getNotifications: () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notifications'))
```

User can also delete notification by selecting individual items from `getNotifications`.

Now, I am able to delete notifications from backend and localStorage, but how do I force a refresh to the aforementioned `getNotifications` getter?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should use a state to mirror the localstorage, actions to add/edit/delete from localstorage and each action to do related mutation to update mirrored localstorage. Localstorage should be used for persistance only. Treat localstorage like a rest api you get/put/post to and update the vuex with response. In fact all rest api are kind of "localstorages" of another computer.

Comment: @MatJ You are right but I don't want to store notifications in variables. The getter above is just fetching the notifications which are stored in local storage.

Comment: You should stop thinking about vuex as variables and start treating it as your state store first. Vuex is your store. Anything outside is external to your app. Otherwise you'll find many roadblocks like these.